# html2canvas image save in Interner explorer

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I want to save the div as a image using HTML2Canvas, I am using Ie10+, and below is my code

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('bgcolor')], {
                letterRendering: true,
                allowTaint: true,
                imageSmoothingEnabled: true,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",'1.0'); 
                    var output = img.replace('data:image/png;base64,', 'image/octet-stream');
                    var output = encodeURIComponent(img);
                    var Parameters = "image=" + output + '&template=' + '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('templatimg'); ?>';
                    img.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    img.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    img.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>saveimage.php",
                        data: Parameters,
                        success: function(data) {  



                                }
                            }); 
                        }
                    }).done(function() {
                    });
                }
            });
```

This code is working but image is getting stretched and quality is also low. In PHP I am using Imagick to save the image. In chrome and Firefox there is no issue.

Comment: I found the solution for IE9 and 10, using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">, But same is not working on IE11. I am using  html2canvas 0.4.1 API.